# My Realtek RTL8152 adapter doesn't work in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, network-adapter, adapter, usb-network-adapter

I have a Realtek RTL8152 ethernet to usb adapter but it doesn't work with my kali even after installing its drivers. I know it is not broken because when i use it with my windows machine it works perfectly fine. Kali Linux recognizes my adapter but it doesn't connect to the network.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy14E.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Due to the nature of the Kali operating system it may assume that you want to set up network interfaces yourself for the various networks you might be using it in. Look at the "Kali Linux network configuration from DHCP" section at https://www.cyberpratibha.com/blog/using-the-command-line-to-configure-network-interface-in-kali-linux/

Comment: After running dhclient i get this output: 
`Listening on LPF/eth0/00:e0:4c:36:17:35 Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:e0:4c:36:17:35 Sending on   Socket/fallback DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 No DHCPOFFERS received. No working leases in persistent database - sleeping
`

Comment: Look for a Kali Driver for the card.  You might also try a Debian driver.

Comment: As I've said in the question I already installed drivers for it but it still doesn't work